# Como fazer múltiplas requisições HTTP dentro de um loop com JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

O que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte: preciso enviar uma requisição em que deve ser retornado um ID, assim que recuperar esse ID disparo outra requisição que finalmente cadastra os dados no servidor. Esse processamento deve ser feito em uma estrutura de repetição que itera minha lista de tarefas em que, a cada iteração deverão ser feitas duas requisições uma para buscar o id do usuário outra para cadastrar uma tarefa.

Ex:

```
function consulta_retorna_id(nome){
    return get_id(nome);
 }

 function insere_tarefa(id, tarefa){
    set_tarefa(id, tarefa);
 }

 //person = arquivo json local
 for (x in person) {

    var id = consulta_retorna_id(person[x].nome);
    insere_tarefa(id,person[x].nome);

}
```

Meu desafio está sendo trabalhar com o assincronismo das chamadas http, uma vez que as requisição acontecem de forma independente porém devem obedecer um fluxo de execução em que primeiro recupero o id depois insere

Comment: Legal e o que você já fez? Onde exatamente está encontrando alguma dificuldade?

Comment: Ainda não fiz o código, não consegui bolar um estratégia pra resolver isso

Comment: Se o id do usuário que irá buscar na primeira requisição for o id do usuário logado, então guarde em local/session storage em vez de fazer requisições a toa. O site pra ajudar problemas específicos, faça a estrutura base do código da forma que sabe,  se você tiver uma dúvida, então pergunte

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Não, o usuário não esta logado

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução que utilizo são funções de callback, que só são executada após a requisição ter sucesso, veja o código abaixo como ficaria.

```js
function get_id(nome, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    /* sua configuracao ajax*/
    success: function() {
      var id = /*sua configuracaopara obter id*/ ;

      if (callback) {
        callback(id)
      }
    }
  });
}

function insere_tarefa(id, tarefa) {
  set_tarefa(id, tarefa);
}

for (x in person) {

  get_id(person[x].nome, function(id) { //funciton callback
    insere_tarefa(id, person[x].nome);
  });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Nesse caso o loop continua assíncrono? no meu caso pretendo cadastrar uma tarefa assim que a anterior for cadastrada o que seria síncrono.

Comment: para que sua requisições ajax  seja síncronas você pode adicionar o atributo async=false nos parâmetros do ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/